# Error when accessing singleton class of object (https://srb.help/3001)

Tags: ruby, sorbet

When I access the singleton class of an object using the following code

```
(class << object; self; end)
```

The `srb` command raises an error:

```
class << EXPRESSION is only supported for class << self https://srb.help/3001
```

Due to special circumstances (proxy/mock object) I *cannot* call any methods on the object. The object especially is extremely unenthusiastic about being asked about `singleton_class`, `instance eval`, `instance_exec` or `binding`, so I need to use this expression.

How can I suppress this error? Wrapping the expression in `T.unsafe` did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your best bet is to isolate this test (I assume it is due to the proxy/mock reference) in its own file and mark that file as `typed: ignore`. Since the error is a processing stage error (specifically, 3xxx errors are from the desugaring stage where code is being rewritten for simpler representation), it won't be suppressible with `T.unsafe` or other methods.